# How to save user's custom input with a list of predetermined item

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a database which contain a list of items (`item`)

```
+----+-----------------------+-------+--------+-------+
| id | name                  | width | height | depth |
+----+-----------------------+-------+--------+-------+
|  1 | Some_toy              |    35 |     28 |    30 |
|  2 | Pepperoni_pizza       |    17 |     30 |    35 |
|  3 | Wood_table            |    45 |     42 |    57 |
|  4 | Guitar                |    26 |     45 |    75 |
|  5 | Awesome_TV            |    80 |     35 |    10 |
+----+-----------------------+-------+--------+-------+
```

On my website, users can select items inside this list to create their own list of item. User's list are stored in the following table `user_list_items`

```
+----+--------------+---------+--------+
| id | id_user_list | id_item | number |
+----+--------------+---------+--------+
|  1 |            6 |       3 |      2 |
|  2 |            6 |       5 |      1 |
|  3 |            6 |       7 |      5 |
|  4 |            7 |       7 |      3 |
|  5 |            9 |       3 |      1 |
+----+--------------+---------+--------+
```

But, because my list cannot contain every item in the world, I want to allow users to add a  custom item.

My problem is that I don't want to store users custom items inside my table `item` because this table contains the item displayed by default.

However, If I don't save custom items inside my table `item`, I still must save them somewhere else. So I've created another table `custom_item` which is an exact replica of `item`. 
With this solution, I've added a foreign key `id_custom_item` in my table `user_list_items` which give the following

```
+----+--------------+---------+----------------+--------+
| id | id_user_list | id_item | id_custom_item | number |
+----+--------------+---------+----------------+--------+
|  1 |            6 |       3 |              0 |      2 |
|  2 |            6 |       0 |             25 |      1 |
|  3 |            6 |       7 |              0 |      5 |
|  4 |            7 |       7 |              0 |      3 |
|  5 |            9 |       3 |              0 |      1 |
+----+--------------+---------+----------------+--------+
```

And now I have a problem with `user_list_items` because can link to `item` or to `custom_item` and it seems like a very bad practice.

My question is, how could I save user's custom input with a list of predetermined item ?
Sorry this question is not very well formulated but I couldn't find any other way to express it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objection to storing custom items in item table is just that the contents are displayed by default, I'd add a column set to 'Y' or 'N' to the table and add that column to the WHERE clause of the query that populates the default list, eg AND default_flag = 'Y'

Comment: Well, it works, i would prefer to keep my table clean (without any custom item) but it seems like the only solution. Thanks =)